# Is there any Source Code Analysis/Quality tool for HiveQL?

Tags: hive, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins, hiveql, code-analysis

I googled a lot to get Source Code Analyzer for HiveQL but didn't find any such tool.

I have checked all the plugins in SonarQube but there is no plugin for HiveQL.

Is there any Source Code Analysis/Quality tool for HiveQL?